# Mapping of CoreOS version and Max supported Ignition version

Tags: coreos

CoreOS (both Traditional CoreOS and Fedora CoreOS) use Ignition config,
could anyone tell me the map of OS version and Max supported Ignition version? It is surprisingly difficult to find.

Please do not provide me https://coreos.github.io/ignition/specs/, which does not say the relation of ignition version and os version.